# sha256sum: /path/filename: No such file or directory

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to install `anaconda`. I'm following the [official instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) but when I get to the second step, I run the following command:

```
$ sha256sum /path/filename
sha256sum: /path/filename: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Hi, I rolled back your last edit. Since the solution is already provided in the accepted answer, there is no need to also add it to the question. This could only confuse a user with the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems OP didn't adapt the command to his computer.

In the command `sha256sum /path/filename`, there is 3 parts :

- `sha256sum` is the command to show the file hash value
- `path` is the path to reach the Anaconda installer, so it's the Download file in the OP case
- `filename` is the name of the Anaconda installer, the current name is `Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh`

So the command would be :

```
sha256sum ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

It would return the hash of the file, which you have to compare on the link where you donwload it; if it's **NOT** the same, **don't use it**, it could be a malware or just the file corrupt itself during download.

Hash list of Anaconda installer : https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/hashes/all/

As you can see in the screenshot below, I use your hash result and find that you download a good installer, not corrupted nor malware :

[image]

Comment: I following from the website, I need this for university.

Comment: @SeemsToBeStuck it's not the same issue, and *I think* you just need to choose the university version when running the installer

Comment: I can continue with the emulator.